# Measuring Class Dependencies

Tags: .net, class, dependencies, measurement

I want to measure dependencies between **classes** - what's the best approach and tools to use?

I'm working in MS .Net

Text based information / reports are OK, but I'd prefer something visual.

Open source tool would be ideal.

Answer (score 2):

This may not help (right now), but it looks like VS 2010 will have a [dependency graph feature](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/11/05/visual-studio-2010-visualizing-dependencies.aspx) out of the box. Looks like it will do class, namespace, and assembly dependencies.